# Группировка с использованием пользовательской функции для агрегации

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Имеется DataFrame такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сгруппировать данные по филиалам и получить общую сумму по колонке сумма для каждого филиала. Но кроме суммы нужно получить еще расчетную среднюю величину для каждого филиала, и в этом заключается проблема.

Средняя должна считаться следующим образом: для каждой группы (филиала) считается сумма произведений величины "сумма" на величину "срок" и делится на сумму по колонке "сумма" для этой группы.

Методом проб мне удалось сделать такой рабочий код:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df_samp.csv')  # ссылка на файл с фрагментом данных внизу
togroup = df[['филиал', 'сумма', 'срок']][df['срок']>90]  # группируем только строки где "срок" > 90
togroup['средн'] = np.NaN  # добавил столбец для средних значений
grouped = togroup.groupby('филиал').agg(lambda x: int(sum(x.сумма*x.срок)/sum(x.сумма)))[['сумма', 'средн']]
```

На выходе получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно сами вопросы:

1. как правильно составить функцию для агрегирования (не уверен что мой способ правильный\лучший)?
2. как сделать чтобы в колонке сумма была итоговая сумма, а не дублировалось среднее (не получается задать для каждой колонки свою функцию)?
3. есть ли способ не вставлять пустой столбец для итоговых данных, а создать его "на лету" при группировке?

UPD: фрагмент данных в формате [csv](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/V5AZ3Lc-pVj1fQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужно получить две новые колонки на основании вычислений. Вероятно, можно сделать так:

```
res = df[df['срок']>90].groupby('филиал')[['филиал', 'сумма', 'срок']].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({"сумм": x["сумма"].sum(), "сред": (x["сумма"]*x["срок"]).sum()/x["сумма"].sum()}))
```

Тогда для вашего примера результат будет таким:

```
                                             сумм         сред
филиал                                                        
Алтайский КРТПЦ                         736451.97  1488.739564
Волгоградский ОРТПЦ                          0.70  1281.000000
Воронежский ОРТПЦ                        98343.38  1115.403130
Дальневосточный РЦ                     1149160.45   458.215772
Забайкальский КРТПЦ                     103737.64   750.595304
Камчатский КРТПЦ                           960.44   367.000000
Краснодарский КРТПЦ                     482443.26   291.000000
Курганский ОРТПЦ                         90024.04   508.825266
Магаданский ОРТПЦ                        57254.29   496.717449
Московский РЦ                          4129843.28   820.056739
Нижегородский ОРТПЦ                     812323.32   169.279333
РТПЦ Еврейской АО                           72.00   946.000000
РТПЦ Кабардино-Балкарской Республики    124682.40   504.500000
РТПЦ Карачаево-Черкесской Республики    680824.77   563.927502
РТПЦ Республики Калмыкия                  1049.90  1914.730536
РТПЦ Республики Коми                    180949.45  1226.852839
РТПЦ Республики Крым                  15260435.65   958.266395
РТПЦ Республики Тыва                     23280.00   108.000000
РТПЦ Чувашской Республики                 3658.38  1845.862666
Саратовский ОРТПЦ                        26066.24   141.016411
Свердловский ОРТПЦ                         967.23   885.000000
Сибирский РЦ                             32272.12   442.000000
Тульский ОРТПЦ                          101816.17   494.907639
Урало-Сибирский РЦ                      620750.47   500.127947
Челябинский ОРТПЦ                        68354.00   797.511367
```

Разумеется, нужно перепроверить.

Comment: спасибо, это работает. Теперь пытаюсь разобраться КАК это работает)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
res = (df
       [['филиал', 'сумма', 'срок']]
       .query("срок > 90")
       .assign(сред=df["сумма"]*df["срок"])
       .groupby("филиал")
       .agg(
           сумм=("сумма","sum"), 
           сред=("сред", "sum"))
       .eval("сред = сред / сумм"))
```

результат:

```
In [129]: res
Out[129]:
                                             сумм         сред
филиал
Алтайский КРТПЦ                         736451.97  1488.739564
Волгоградский ОРТПЦ                          0.70  1281.000000
Воронежский ОРТПЦ                        98343.38  1115.403130
Дальневосточный РЦ                     1149160.45   458.215772
Забайкальский КРТПЦ                     103737.64   750.595304
Камчатский КРТПЦ                           960.44   367.000000
Краснодарский КРТПЦ                     482443.26   291.000000
Курганский ОРТПЦ                         90024.04   508.825266
Магаданский ОРТПЦ                        57254.29   496.717449
Московский РЦ                          4129843.28   820.056739
Нижегородский ОРТПЦ                     812323.32   169.279333
РТПЦ Еврейской АО                           72.00   946.000000
РТПЦ Кабардино-Балкарской Республики    124682.40   504.500000
РТПЦ Карачаево-Черкесской Республики    680824.77   563.927502
РТПЦ Республики Калмыкия                  1049.90  1914.730536
РТПЦ Республики Коми                    180949.45  1226.852839
РТПЦ Республики Крым                  15260435.65   958.266395
РТПЦ Республики Тыва                     23280.00   108.000000
РТПЦ Чувашской Республики                 3658.38  1845.862666
Саратовский ОРТПЦ                        26066.24   141.016411
Свердловский ОРТПЦ                         967.23   885.000000
Сибирский РЦ                             32272.12   442.000000
Тульский ОРТПЦ                          101816.17   494.907639
Урало-Сибирский РЦ                      620750.47   500.127947
Челябинский ОРТПЦ                        68354.00   797.511367
```

Comment: спасибо, очень понятный код. Возьму такой способ на вооружение.